# Facturas recibidas

Tags: aeat-sii

Estoy trabajando en pruebas con envío de información del SII. Con la versión 1.0 estoy teniendo problemas con las facturas recibidas.

Tengo un XML y al enviarlo me devuelve el error:

> ```
> 4124 - Error La dirección no se corresponde con el fichero de entrada.
> ```

He estado mirando ejemplos, y la documentación y soy incapaz de solucionarlo. ¿Alguien me puede dar una pista? Muchas gracias.

Os dejo el XML de ejemplo (está recortado y me he centrado en lo que ocasiona el error)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:siiLR="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd"
    xmlns:sii="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas></siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Buenas tardes Jorge
Puedes poner un ejemplo ??

Comment: Buenas noches, Sería de agradecer que "pegaras" un ejemplo de como ha quedado, estoy en el mismo error que tú y no se por dónde tirar... Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Explico algo mejor cual era su problema según entiendo yo, y la simple solución:

Para enviar documentos al SII en la web dela agencia tributaria tenemos que ir al apartado de "Cliente de Web Service" ó "Cliente de Web Service para el entorno de pruebas"

El entrar en ese entorno de envío, nos aparece por defecto la siguiente URL:

```
URL Endpoint (sin dominio): /wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP
```

Esa dirección es la que se usa para enviar Facturas Emitidas.
Pero si lo que queremos es enviar una Factura Recibida, esa URL tenemos que cambiarla por:

```
/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactFRV1SOAP
```

(fijense que la URL es muy parecida, y tan solo cambia 'fe' por 'fr', y SiiFactFE... por SiiFactFR...)

Asi de simple.

Answer (score 1):

El tema lo he solucionado y como en estos casos suele ser, es fruto de la obcecación.

La solución,  es que en la página de pruebas tenemos que acondicionar el END POINT correcto, que por defecto coge para facturas emitidas.

Comment: Para futuros lectores, ¿podrías aclarar cuál sería y cómo quedaría?

Comment: Hay 7 servicios web cuyas definiciones se encuentran en http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web.shtml y dentro cada fichero de definición vienen los endpoints para cada entorno. En http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/ explica como manejar los servicios y entornos fácilmente.